# how to reaplce any value in file with single backslash in java

Tags: java

```
String newContent = oldContent.replace("\\", "\");
```

A windows  path in a config file which is being modified by another program with \
After that i running this code to replace all \\ with \

Comment: As you can see in your own line of code, `"\"` is not a valid `String`… By the way, what exactly is your question? Have you tried `oldContent.replace("\\\\", "\\")`?

Comment: Windows servers can have UNC names starting with 2 backslashes `\\SHARE1\D$\Docs`

Comment: thanks its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 oldContent.replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

Comment: please check again

Answer (score 0):

```
String newContent = oldContent.replace("\\\\", "\\");
```